# I can't add a strongly-typed view to MVC project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

First of all, when I right click on the Action Result method name there is no option for creating a view, only "Go to view" even it doesn't exist.

[I added a view to the folder by "Add" -> "MVC 5 View Page (Razor)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToiUw.jpg), but in dialog window [I can type only the name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLNaH.png)

How to create a strongly-typed view?

Answer (score 1):

In recent update to web developer tooling they re added this functionality for mvc5/4 projects.
https://get.asp.net/

Comment: delete .vs/projectname/v14/.suo file, also you should look for add controller menu item, not add item

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@model` directive to specify the type.

Example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
@model MyModel

<p>@Model.MyString</p>
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor